# Calculating a filter's attenuation at a certain frequency from the Q-factor

Tags: filters, frequency-spectrum, frequency, bandpass, bandwidth

I'm using the Web Audio API to make a graphic EQ with four BiQuad filters; a highpass, two bandpass and a low pass:

[image]

You can see each node representing each filter's frequency. It's working nicely but I'd like to draw the shape of the filter's roll-off you'd usually find in other graphic EQ's.

I have the Q-factor of each filter and the central frequency. What I would like to do is get a formula that allows me to get the frequency of the roll-off at a specific db value. For example what is the frequency of the roll-off at -200db?

It's been a while since I've done any heavy mathematical stuff and so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The Q factor and center frequency won't be enough to plot the full frequency response of a filter. You'll need to know its topology (e.g. Butterworth, Chebyshev, others) and order.

Comment: These are BiQuad filters. Do I need to be more specific than that?

Comment: Yes. You can calculate the frequency response from the coefficients directly, or if you're using a well-known topology, there may be cookbook equations that you can use instead.

Comment: ok thanks. So I don't currently have enough information on these filters to do a calculation - correct? The filter's code is hidden behind an API so I'm not sure if I can get more info on them but I'll take a look about...

Comment: I think I found the appropriate cookbook [here](http://www.musicdsp.org/files/Audio-EQ-Cookbook.txt)